# Windows 7 + IE 10 Non compatibility mode sometimes click events don't trigger

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-10, compatibility-mode

I have a web site that has Always worked in compatibility mode from IE7 to IE11.
In my grids I have a classic "onclick" event.
I have refreshed the layout of the page (is most a single page application) and i have inserted some iframe managed with Signalr.
The web site works now in non compatibility mode and sometimes, seems randomly, when a user open a grid the "onclick" event isn't triggered, even if it's present in the DOM.
If i change manually the DOM (with F12) adding, for example, an alert before the javascript function it starts to work.

```
<table class="search-table" id="gvDati" style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="1" rules="all" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
    <tr style="cursor: pointer; background-color: white;" onmouseenter="CustomGridViewColora(this)" onmouseleave="CustomGridViewScolora(this)">
    </td>
    <td style="white-space: nowrap;" onclick="MyJavascriptFunction('parameter1','0')">-00125</td>
    <td style="white-space: nowrap;" onclick="MyJavascriptFunction('parameter1','0')">AD</td>
    <td style="white-space: nowrap;" onclick="MyJavascriptFunction('parameter1','0')">1</td>
    <td style="white-space: nowrap;" onclick="MyJavascriptFunction('parameter1','0')">2</td>
    <td style="white-space: nowrap;" onclick="MyJavascriptFunction('parameter1','0')">3</td>
    <td style="white-space: nowrap;" onclick="MyJavascriptFunction('parameter1','0')">4</td>
    <td style="white-space: nowrap;" onclick="MyJavascriptFunction('parameter1','0')">ACF</td>
    <td style="white-space: nowrap;" onclick="MyJavascriptFunction('parameter1','0')">Sì</td>
    <td style="white-space: nowrap;" onclick="MyJavascriptFunction('parameter1','0')">TEST</td>
    <td style="white-space: nowrap;" onclick="MyJavascriptFunction('parameter1','0')">SI</td>
    <td onclick="MyJavascriptFunction('parameter1','0')">
        <img onclick="" src="immagini/asd.png">
        </td>
        <td onclick="MyFunction1('-00125')">
            <img onclick="" src="immagini/acm.png">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is a piece of a rendered html. It has nothing strange, i see...

Is there an unknown bug or similar?
I'm sorry for the lack of information, but i haven't see an anomaly like this, before

Thanks

Comment: The issue could be in MyFunction, if you set an break point on top of that function, does it trigger?

Comment: No, i have a breakpoint on this function...